# How can I get an appID and secret to get my facebook graph api working?

Tags: facebook

I have tried this page: http://developers.facebook.com/setup/ but it's not working. I think it's not working since july. Is there another way to get the an appID and secret?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to http://www.facebook.com/developers/ and select your app from the list.

Comment: lol. then why did facebook say that an error has been encourted? :)